# Sorting in Excel without using VB code

Tags: excel

I have this data in an Excel spreadsheet. I want to sort the data in ascending order using Column 1 and want to keep the respective columns in order. The first 6 data is to be sorted first and then the next 11 data. I have similar kind of huge set of data with different sizes which i want to sort in Excel.

Can anyone guide me on the efficient method to do this?

```
2   1101    TATE'S CAIRN TUNNEL
3   12406   WATER SPORTS CENTRE
4   12407   HONG KONG INSTITUTE OF BIOTECHNOLOGY
5   12408   HONG KONG SCIENCE PARK
6   13183   HONG KONG SCIENCE PARK PHASE III
1   1146    DIAMOND HILL RAILWAY STATION BUS TERMINUS

6   6588    FANLING RAILWAY STATION
7   6582    PAK FUK TIN SUM PLAYGROUND
8   6579    DAWNING VIEWS
9   6575    WO HING TSUEN
10  6585    WAH MING BUS TERMINUS
11  6586    WAH MING BUS TERMINUS
1   6586    WAH MING BUS TERMINUS
2   6584    YAN SHING COURT
3   6589    FUNG YING SIN KOON
4   6591    KEI SAN SECONDARY SCHOOL
5   6590    KEI SAN SECONDARY SCHOOL
```

Comment: Have you tried sorting from the menu?

Comment: Do you want to sort it automatically(using macro vba code) or manually?

Comment: I want to automate the sorting since the data list is huge. But the data are of different lengths, ex: first list is of 8, then 11 etc. I don't have the length of the data set as well.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight/Select the range to be sorted.

Click on Data tab.

Click on Sort and follow the Wizard's instructions. Which includes choosing what columns to sort on etc.